# How to log the required part of a file using apache camel.?

Tags: apache-camel

How to log part of the incoming data in the console and log file?

Suppose, I am getting input from File source and It contains the Sales Order. I want to log all the Sales Order number.

Input :

```
<root>
<records>
  <salesorderno> 10002<salesorderno>


</records>
    <salesorderno> 10005<salesorderno>
<records>

</records>
<records>
   <salesorderno> 10032<salesorderno>

</records>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XPATH expression to get the values. Something like:

```
from("file:inbox")
.setHeader("salesordernos", xpath("/root/records/salesorderno"))
.to("log:loggerName?showBody=true&showHeaders=true");
```